# Dont try to evaluate data-bind before variable is set

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In knockout is there a way to tell it to wait with evaluating certain parts of the html until a value is set?

This first method is what I currently do to make it work and the bottom one is what I would like to have (or similar).

```
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: ObservableThing() != null ? ObservableThing().Name : ''">
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: isReady()">
    <span data-bind="text:ObservableThing().Name">
</div>
```

I'm certain someone has been annoyed at this before and solved it.. if it's not already built in and Im just not finding it.

Edit: for some more context. The Observable thing is defined like this: `model.ObservableThing = ko.observable();` and it is set by a jQuery.Get call at some point by this code: `model.ObservableThing (resultData);`

Comment: You can use `if: ObservableThing, text: ObservableThing`

Comment: @haim770 that does not seem to work: "Multiple bindings (if and text) are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element. You cannot use these bindings together"

Answer (score 0):

Was easy enough, use an if.

```
<div data-bind="if: isReady()">
    <span data-bind="text:ObservableThing().Name">
</div>
```

and it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'ObservableThing' is a complex object, bind it using a with binding and all descendants can be bound to 'ObservableThing's properties. It'll be cleaner and better than using an if as knockout will determine when to render 'ObservableThing' and its elements.

```
<div data-bind="with: ObservableThing">
    <span data-bind="Name">
</div>
```

have a look at this link for more info: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html